# What impact does simulated metrics have?

Tags: ios, xcode

When using .xib files what impact on your code/app does changing simulated metrics have? Or is it just for your benefit as a preview tool?

Comment: If you choose Simulated Metric -> Size, then specify the size of your view in Xib file, this view will have this size when loaded

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **Simulated Metrics** are mostly a design aid to help you lay out your interface.  They have little direct impact on the .xib*[1].  They are very helpful because you can simulate things like your view controller being imbedded in a navigation controller, which gives you less space to work with since the navigation bar takes up some space.  They are also very handy if you are laying out a viewController that will only be used in landscape.  At the time they were introduced, it was the only way to check how your interface would look on the shorter iPhone 4 display and the taller iPhone 5 display*[2].

I frequently set the **Size** to *iPhone 4 inch* because: 1) I find working in the square viewController distracting, 2) It takes up much less screen real estate allowing me to see more of my Storyboard on my laptop display.  This method is much less dangerous that changing the size class to **wC hR** because the latter will actually affect which constraints are used for different sized devices.

---

[1] The **Size** and **Orientation** metrics will affect the size of the viewController as it is stored in the `.xib` or `.storyboard` file.  If you leave the setting as *Inferred*, Xcode will use `600 x 600` as the viewController's size.  Normally, this makes no difference, because the viewController will be properly sized to the device when it loads.

[2] At the time *Simulated Metrics* were introduced, this was *the way* to test designs for the iPhone 4s vs. the new taller iPhone 5.  Apple has since introduced other better ways of checking out designs on various sized devices.

Comment: Cool, thanks! So they are no real help if everything is laid out programmatically, which in the app I'm working on, is the case.  Thanks vacawama.

Comment: I have a view controller (in a storyboard), that if I change the "size" simulated metrics from "inferred" to 3.5inch, the UITableView I'm using is the correct height to allow the user to scroll all the way to the bottom.

Comment: In this case, it seems changing the simulated metrics has a direct impact on my app? I'm testing on a real device.

Comment: @drc Changing the orientation in the simulated metrics also changes it in the simulator - if e.g. I use landscape and start the simulator in portrait, it will show the viewcontroller in landscape... so a part of it is cut... doesn't make sense to me... is it a bug in XCode maybe? (using XCode 5.0.2)

Answer (score 15):

Well actually changing the Simulated Metrics does impact your application in a very sneaky way. I found that out while using the SwipeView library and my slides were all impacted by changing the Simulated Metric size.

Under the hood changing that size sets the rect value of the nib file as such:

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
```

That value is gonna be the size the nib launches. If we try to measure elements in view did load and view will appear we will have false information:

```
// viewDidLoad
(lldb) po splashImageView
<UIImageView: 0x79913eb0; frame = (0 0; 600 600); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x799ca310>>


// viewWillAppear
(lldb) po splashImageView
<UIImageView: 0x79913eb0; frame = (0 0; 600 600); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x799ca310>>
```

Once the layout subviews is done we do have the proper size but as far as SwipeView is concerned it's too late it already calculated the position of everything.

```
// viewDidLayoutSubviews
(lldb) po splashImageView
<UIImageView: 0x79913eb0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x799ca310>>
```

If anyone can provide more information I'd really like it.

Comment: Good to know; this can be particularly annoying when you want to programmatically initialize view content in awakeFromNib and it's not the right size yet!

Comment: Hi Hugo... Did you get around this issue? I'm using swipeView and have run into this issue myself. Unless I change the simulated metrics, it does not come correctly on the device. How to get around this issue?

Comment: @momentsnapper I did not, in the end this old application I was working on had a lot more work required to really be multi screen size. I kept the Simulated Metrics at a iPhone 5 screen size.

Comment: The size also affects visibly the layout when the view is loaded. If you for example use "inferred" (600x600) and centered a view using constraints, when the app runs on an iPhone you see it animating from the right-bottom, that is, from the center of 600x600. I set it to 4.7 inches, now it looks good in this screen, but not the others. Looks like a bug to me, the idea of autolayout it that you should not have to care about the screen size......

Comment: This was the real fix for my problem. If your app builds differently when you have different devices or orientations selected in the Device Bar, you're probably reading the size of something in viewDidLoad(). Do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews() instead.

Answer (score 6):

Watch [WWDC 2015 Session 407 Implementing UI Designs in Interface Builder](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/407), they talked about Simulated Metrics

[image]

**Inferred**

> Now, right now they are all saying inferred. Inferred just basically
>   means use the context around me. We know we are inside a tab bar
>   controller, we know that we're inside a nav controller so interface
>   builder knows which bar to show.

**Simulated Metrics**

> All of these metrics do not affect your actual application at runtime
>   with one exception and that's the size simulated metric.
>
> The size simulated metric will actually change the size of your view
>   controller but generally you're going to put it into a view controller
>   hierarchy which will resize it, but it's also helpful if you are
>   creating free form view controllers, for example, and want to set your
>   own size.