# Xcode Swift tableview cell seperator lines being cut off

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview

I was wondering if anyone new how to solve ths problem I am having with the sepeartor lines instead of the offset being on left as in most google searches mine is on the right any idea how to remove i tried

```
    myTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

But it didnt work

I dont have image uploads rights so here is a link to image

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0173ux9ad1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking what your problem is comes down to not having AutoLayout constraints set properly.

Select your table view in your storyboard and make certain that you *pin* the left and right sides to the parent view.

Here is what it looks like when I do it in Xcode:

[image: Add Constraints]

I clicked the "Add Constraints" bottom after setting the left and right margins to be "0" pixels separated between the left and right margins of the parent view.

Comment: that did it thanks also any good sites or tips on styling the tableview i wanna make something simiar to flixster as a learning curve

Comment: one another note how do you account for the tranculence top status bar my items always overlap just the same principle do u use

Comment: Your follow up question is actually a separate question and I would normally tell you to just ask a new question, [but it's also a question that has been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687082/how-do-i-make-my-ios7-uitableviewcontroller-not-appear-under-the-top-status-bar) (I linked it for you).  Hope this helps!