# Status Bar appearing over the top of Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I've seen a few posts on here regarding this issue, and I've tried all the fixes, but I still can't seem to get this to work.

I have an iOS7 app which uses a Storyboard. The First view is a TableViewController. When I run the app, the status bar with the battery level and signal level seems to be showing over the top of the tableview.

I want the status bar to show, with the tableview directly underneath. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Screenshot of the problem [image]

Thanks y'all!

Comment: increment the reputation it will help to other

Comment: You can embed the UITableViewController in a UINavigationController. Refer to this [UITableView shows under status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18900428/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is status bar issue.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
{
     self.edgesForExtendedLayout=NO;
}
```

or

In your Appdelegate

```
 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {

    self.window=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window];

     self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,-20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height+20);
    }
```

[ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar)

Comment: The second option worked a treat. I do hope this is a bug in XCode, as it seems rather shoddy relying on redrawing the rectangle to show the status bar.

Comment: No it's not a bug. see the different between co-ordinate system of iOS 6 & iOS 7