# Adjusting uitableview height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a simple application with uitableview. I want to create everything in code. I used following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    FBVCalendarViewController *calendarViewController = [[FBVCalendarViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = calendarViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

...

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UITableView *calendarItems = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    self.view = calendarItems;
}
```

it works, but application fills the entire phone screen intersecting with standard phone title bar.

What is the right way to adjust view height?

Comment: You should read a beginners tutorial first.

Comment: this is part of the new iOS 7 stye, as mentioned you need to read tutorials

Comment: please read this first http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Comment: These tutorials use xib files and I don't want to use them.

Comment: Why don't you want to use xibs? Either way, you can use auto layout to constrain your views, but alas that requires more tutorials.

Comment: What is the reason behind not wanting to use XIBs or Storyboards? They are recommended by Apple even.

Comment: Currently my view only contains one tableview and I don't want to introduce additional complexity with XIB. Also I want to better understand how UIKit works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my problem with the following code in loadView:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UITableView *calendarItems = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];

    UIView *rootView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [rootView addSubview:calendarItems];
    self.view = rootView;
}
```

I used empty UIView as a parent for tableView and changed constructor to explicitly specify UITableView frame. I think that better approach would be to use autolayout (currently it just does not work as expected when I rotate device) and position table view to the full screen or implement device rotation callback and update frame there.

Answer (score 2):

Since `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, you should take care of the changes appeared with `IOS 7`.

A solution to your problem is:

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {

        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    }
```

(this will keep the table view below the status bar).

Hope that helps. But you should probably have a  look at changes introduced with IOS 7.

Comment: I tried to add this code in the end of the loadView or viewDidLoad but nothing changed.

Comment: Could you try adding self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone; inside the if too ?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't help too.

Comment: Have a look here, something is weird with this view and I can't figure out what is it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar)