# UITableView overlaps with NavigationBar in Storyboard Setting on first run

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I know this seems to be a duplicate question which has been around here many many times, but believe me, I tried all iOS7 and earlier fixes which sets the Layout to a different Edge configuration without any change.

My Storyboard looks like this:

```
-> Navigation Controller -> Tab Bar Controller -> MyTableViewController -> VCForCellOne
```

With the first run of my application the UITableView overlaps with the source NavigationController as shown here: [image: Overlapsed TableView]

After clicking on one of my Cells which pushes the corresponding ViewController to the NavigationController and going back again, everything looks fine as shown here: [image: How it should be]

So everything is as it should be after once pushing another ViewController to the NavigationController and then going back.

Switching from Portrait to Landscape and back also fixes the layout problem and everything is layed out as it should be.

My ViewController within the Storyboard looks like this: [image: Basic TableView Setup]
I left it the default value, so I don't know what goes wrong here.

I hope you understand my problem here. There's no custom class ViewController here, so no additional code which messes up something here.
Any help highly appreciated!

Update 1:

I guess these information are not pretty new to most of you, but I did some research about what's actually changing when the TableViews gets layout the first time and then again once it's correctly layout after using the Navigation Controller the first time.

So I did check the ContentOffset, contentInset and Bound Values through NSLog in the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear Methods. What I get on the first run (when the overlaps happens):

```
viewWillAppear:
contentOffset(0, 0)
contentInset(0, 0, 0, 0)
BoundsOrigin( 0, 0) BoundsSize( 568, 320)

viewDidAppear:
same results
```

When the relayout happens and everything sits where it should be, the values have an interesting change:

```
viewWillAppear:
contentOffset(0, 0)
contentInset(0, 0, 0, 0)
BoundsOrigin( 0, 0) BoundsSize( 568, 320)

viewDidAppear:
contentOffset(0, -64)
contentInset(64, 0, 0, 0)
BoundsOrigin( 0, -64) BoundsSize( 568, 320)
```

I could rebuild this "bug" with a brand new project by using the same layout without any modifications or something and I always get the same strange behavior.

Comment: Check the first answer. It should work for you? Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar

Comment: As I said in the first lines, it seems to be an duplicate, but setting the edgesForExtendedLayout doesn't work here. Tried it several times before.

Comment: Where in your code did you try to set the edges? Try setting them in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. I did choose my ViewController class as custom class in the Interface Builder and tried to set the edges in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear as well as in viewDidLayoutSubviews as suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best to do is to set the frame of your tableview in your code , that way it is forced to start in a "default" position . Just change the frame property to a CGRectMake and see the best values that fit you .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried that and it seems to work. Though, it's no real solution to my problem as this breaks Auto Layout and is just a workaround for me. The information I collected and just added to the initial Post show when the correct Offset happens and that there's something strange or even a bug.

Comment: i had a problem that was almost like yours , what i did after set the frame to keep the auto layout was . first set the layout to suggested constraints and then in AppDelegate.m i did set the view frame,so that way the tableview keeps cool in both 4" or 3.5" , i don't know if that will work for you . The code i added to AppDelegate.m was self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height);