# Xcode 5 not displaying Top/Bottom Layout Guides for TableViewControllers

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, xcode5, uitableview

The Interface Builder in Xcode 5.1.1 displays *Top Layout Guide* and *Bottom Layout Guides* for *View Controllers* but apparently not for *Table View Controllers*.

Is this indeed (always) the case and what is the reason why?

[image]

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the layout guides are irrelevant in table view controllers. If you need to add other views to a table view controller, you shouldn't be using a table view controller, but a regular view controller with a `UITableView` and any other views you'd like.