# UITableView contentOffset will not scroll table all the way to the bottom

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Imagine something like this, where the content size is far less than 90000.0f :

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, 90000.0f);
```

After this is called, my table *almost* scrolls to the bottom of the view but there is about ~30.0f worth of extra scroll view that I have to move to get the table to actually scroll to the bottom.

How can I programmatically get my table to the bottom?

Comment: check the content insets of the scrollview

Comment: I didn't set an edge inset - all (0,0,0,0)

Comment: Do you have some sample code I could throw in a test project and try to replicate/fix?

Comment: You say you haven't added any insets. Have you checked if the VC has added any? The accepted answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar) **might** help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try scrolling to you last `tableViewCell`?

```
//for instance, you have 15 cells
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:14 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                              animated:YES];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```