# UITableView Interfering with Status Bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, statusbar

I am working on an app that has a UITableViewController that displays a list of values as so:

[image: ScreenShot]

How can I shift the table down such that it doesn't clash with my status bar? It seems that I can't apply any constraints to this scene so I'm at a loss.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Use the following 3 properties on your `UIViewController`

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

Comment: This does not work for a UITableViewController embedded inn a TabBarController.

Comment: This answer is nearly a year old, most likely it worked at the time. I can not be expected to maintain answers so they work with each new version of iOS. Hardly a reason for a down vote IMO.

Comment: To be honest, I tried to change the downvote, but it was´t possible any more - so I wrote the comment. Yes I really made a mistake with this first downvote in my live, but it seems like I can´t correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Set `edgesForExtendedLayout` for the ViewController to `UIRectEdgeNone` in your `viewDidLoad()` method. This will start the tableview from below the status bar

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on iOS 9. In your view controller viewDidLoad() -

```
self.yourTableViewReference.contentInset.top = 20
self.yourTableViewReference.scrollIndicatorInsets.top = 20
```