# first string of table view is in status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

how can do that "apple" stay under status bar and not into status bar?

Thanks in advance everybody!

[image]

> this is my file.xib:

[image]

this is my code updated but it doesn't work....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    arOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   /* for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        [arOptions addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Option %i", i]];
    }*/
    [arOptions addObject:@"Apple"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Mango"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Papaya"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Guava"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Pineapple"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Strawberry"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Banana"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Grapes"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Pomegranate"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Green Tea"];
    [arOptions addObject:@"Raisin"];
    arSelectedRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UITableView *tblOptions = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tblOptions.delegate = self;
    tblOptions.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tblOptions];
    **self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;**
    UIButton *btnAlert = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnAlert.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.size.height - 50 + 5, self.view.frame.size.width - 20 - 20, 50 - 10);
    [btnAlert setTitle:@"Get_answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnAlert addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAlertTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnAlert];

}
```

Comment: Are you using constraints for designing ?

Comment: [Also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680419/uitableview-interfering-with-status-bar/27683505), and [also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818231/how-to-fix-table-views-search-bar-overlapping-with-status-bar/30818448), and some more…

Comment: i can't find my solution...

Comment: Try UITableView *tblOptions = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

Comment: now many under from status bar