# ios UITableViewController overlapping status bar

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a simple tabbed application whose first tab is a `UITableViewController`. After populating some data, I noticed that the top of the table view overlaps the status bar.

I've tried messing with the `edgesForExtendedLayout` and similar settings, but have not found the magical combo. Does anyone know how to correct this?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new tabbed application
2. Remove the first tab `UIViewController` and replace it with a `UITableViewController`
3. Populate the `UITableView` with some data
4. Run the application

Here's a couple screenshots of the setup and the issue:
[image: Xcode Storyboard]
[image: UITableView overlapping status bar]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just modify the `contentInset` property of your table view, which can add some padding around your content. In `viewDidLoad()` add the following:

```
tableView.contentInset.top = 20
```

In Objective-C, you can't assign to the top directly, so do it like so:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);
```

Of course it can be any arbitrary value, in this case, it is the height of the status bar.

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised this isn't the default. (Apple should check for status bar and set it accordingly.) I settled with `tableView.contentInset.top = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height` because I don't like magic numbers :)

Comment: And you're right about that. ;) Well the reason here is that (since iOS 7) views extend their edges for the full screen by default. If you embed your view in a navigation controller, you'll see that the navigation bar is taken into account automagically (called "top layout guide").

Comment: you probably want to set scrollIndicatorInsets as well

Comment: This doesn't really work so well for me. There is still no backing view so I cannot set the particular color I want there and anyway scrolling the tableview the content still overlaps status content..

Comment: I don't know how but I tried this previously at that time it was not working not it's working well.

Comment: Setting contentInset did not work for my case in iOS 11. iPhone 8. any other way? when scrolling table contents go under the status bar.

Comment: does not work. iOS 11.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in comments, one way is to (in Swift 3):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.contentInset.top = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
}
```

But that not as clean. It is better to [embed the UITableViewController in a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18951786/93540) (Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller) and uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar" in the inspector. No tweaking needed!