# Search freezes in UISearchBar with searchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, search

I have a `UISearchDisplayController` working nicely with a `UISearchBar`. `shouldReloadTableForSearchString` correctly returns results as the user types, but when the user hits the Search button on the keyboard and `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` is triggered, something odd happens *after* the final search results correctly display and the user hits Cancel on the search bar. Once the user reactivates search, the search opens but the cursor doesn't blink, the search results don't display and the keyboard looks locked on every keypress as shown in the attached image. There should be results for "Test", but nothing is happening and something seems to be held up b/c the last pressed key ("T") isn't going back down to the keyboard.

I'm holding off on including code b/c there are a lot of moving parts, but if any code would help, i can quickly include it. Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: it's not just after the user submits the query - if they've touched the resulting `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` after inputting a query to scroll down through the results, and then hit Cancel, they'll see the frozen cursor and broken search once they activate the searchBar again (same image applies).

SECOND UPDATE: this only happens when I hide / unhide the navbar while search is active in viewWillLayoutSubviews. Any ideas? Really appreciate any help!

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive && !profileSelected) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

[image]

LAST UPDATE: when hide/unhide code is placed into searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch and searchDisplayControllerWillHideSearch respectively, the searchBar incorrectly unhides 20px below navbar:[image]

Comment: Can you try moving hiding code out of viewWillLayoutSubviews. It might be getting called multiple times.

Comment: Where is the best place to put this?

Comment: It should be in a separate method triggered by action that hides/unhides navigation bar.

Comment: thanks - the problem is that when i add the code to searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch and searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch, the search bar unhides at 20px below the nav bar. i've tried many many workarounds

Comment: @HariKunwar i added a picture for you. note the dark blue gap between searchbar and navbar

Comment: can you try moving it to searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch(_:) and searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch(_:). See if it helps.

Comment: I feel this is due to status bar space. Can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar

Comment: Already tried :( but thanks

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding this code:

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UISearchDisplayController is using UITableView to show search results. Whenever you scroll or new cells are loaded, viewWillLayoutSubviews is getting called. This is causing the app to freeze. Try moving you setNavigationBarHidden code in a separate method triggered by some other action.