# ios swift - top padding / statusbar

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app where I in the front scene have set an uimageview with top padding 0 to superview

For infor, I am resizing its height runtime using a height constraint.

The odd thing is the top logo now vertically goes 50% into the top statusbar (at least on iphone 4, portrait mode)

I am a bit at loss for wha possible reasons could be as I am still new to ios/swift/xcode

Comment: Does it work properly if you keep height static?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: It worked before when resizing the frame. After using constrains only it ceased to work correctly. Not sure if padding issue. I will try experiment or post cose

Comment: It works setting a op margin for the uimageview to 10, but... well, otherwise it is standard code. It's no normally necessary to set a top margin to make sure stausbar is not covered- right?

Comment: I think this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar