# Swift 3 - table view, how to create space from the top of the phone?

Tags: uitableview, swift3

So I have a table view which looks like the photo provided:

[Example of tableview on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfYUE.png)

My problem is, as you can see, it starts way up at the top, and basically covers the phone battery indicator etc.

How can I make it start further down?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In interface builder set your `tableView`'s `y` origin to `20`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar

Comment: @NiravD I can't seem to find the tableView's y. Could you help me?

Comment: @SteffenLefort What i'm saying is in storyboard start your tableView after status bar means from its y should start at 20 px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I realized I could "embed in navigator" which automatically pushed it down beneath the top.

Answer (score 1):

KEEP IN MIND :  top 20px is for the status bar (date and battery ) and the top 64 px (including status bar) is for the navigation bar. So if you are using any one these bar then you have to left that px from the top.

You can hide navigation bar but not status bar. So design your UI according to it.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
You have to Drag the UITableView under the top_bar, [image]as below

Comment: This didn't work. Using "table view cell" to design my own cells, it won't let me drag the table view at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

    tableView.frame.origin.y = statusBarHeight
  }

}
```