# UITableView shows under status bar and i want status bar to be opaque so that tableview data doesn't overlap with statusbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, statusbar

[iOS 7: UITableView shows under status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar)
I tried all the links and solution but it's not working for me. I have 13 fields to get from the user and each textfield is in a cell of tableview . My tableview have static cells so if I use UIViewController and put a tableview inside it I have to write UITableViewCell classes for each cell because the design of each cell is different and that is very lengthy work to do.

Comment: I don't want to use Dynamic cells in tableview and if i use tableView inside a UIViewController i won't get the option to use static cells

Answer (score -1):

You can put the tableView in the normal UIViewController and then set the content to static cells in the attributes inspector.
This way you can put your custom cells and then access the controls directly inside the UIViewController class.

Comment: this is what i get as error : static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances.