# Loading freeformed xib into UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I encountered strange issue of shrinking xib loaded into `UIScrollView`.

If I make inferred-sized xib and load it into a scroll view it looks fine: http://monosnap.com/image/vZ4EDOAlKLeWNZAqWsVSq87FUvJdHX.png (the arrow shows center of the xib).

But if I set size property to *freeform* position or try to set `frame.size` programmatically, xib collapses horizontally to 20 px totally ignoring desired size: xib settings: http://monosnap.com/image/4SdHEBmrSn1MrnXCMjr88fNn5reCvb.png (grey square is scroll view area).

The way I'm loading the xib is regular:

```
@implementation LearningViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   self.cardView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
   [self.cardScrollView addSubview:self.cardView];
}
```

Maybe I overlook some crucial scroll view behavior conception?

Comment: Simulated metrics only affect how your xib/storyboard is displayed in the interface build (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16280477/654369).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's struggling with the same issue. Looks like this happens if you're trying to load xib that is smaller than scroll view. You can overcome this by adding an empty subview at first and then putting your xib into this subview:

```
UIView *content = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width*3, 300)];
[self.cardScrollView addSubview:content];

self.cardView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
[content addSubview:self.cardView];
```