# UIViewController's view size from Interface Builder is ignored

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I created a `UIViewControler` and for the `view` I set its `Size` *Simulated Metrics* to `Freeform` and its frame size to `320 x 120`.

After loading it in another `UIViewController` like:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

[self addChildViewController:myViewController];

[self.scrollViewContent addSubview:myViewController.view];
```

`myViewController.view` has the size `600 x 600`. Why is that? I also set its background color to red and it's showing up white.

The `xib`'s `File Owner` is correctly set to `MyViewController`.

I don't use `Auto Layout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the project solved the problem, again -_-

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning AutoLayout off?

Answer (score 0):

The simulated metrics serves the purpose of letting developers see how their design would look like with the desired frames (in your case 320 x 120). It does not reflect during runtime of the application. You might want to set some AutoLayout constraints if you want it to remain at 320 x 120.

As for the background color, you can set it programmatically via:

```
myViewController.view.background = [UIColor redColor]
```

Comment: Whaaat? Are you sure? I often set `UIView`s' frames in `Interface Builder` and it always worked; I didn't have to re-set it programmatically. Also, setting the background color in code doesn't explains why it didn't work from `Interface Builder`.

Comment: Funny I always thought they don't apply during runtime as I learned it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279379/what-impact-does-simulated-metrics-have and http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/407.