# Change .xib size on different iPad screen resolution programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a problem displaying HUD in a view of iPad mini/iPad 4 and iPad Pro. It won't go centre as it should be. And I think, it was a problem with my .xib size. It depends on simulated metric setting.

I try to set .xib using simulated metric,

**1. iPad Full Screen**

I set my .xib with iPad Full Screen,

[image: iPad]

And if I opened as source code, it gives me 1024 x 704 resolution.

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="1024" height="704"/>
```

Then I run this on iPad, and my HUD is centered as it should be. But if I run on iPad Pro, my HUD doesn't centre as well. It looks like my HUD still at centre of 1024 x 704.

**2. iPad Pro Full Screen**

I try to set .xib with iPad Pro Full Screen

[image: iPad Pro]

And it gives me 1366 x 960 resolution

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="1366" height="960"/>
```

Then I run this on iPad Pro, and my HUD is centered as it should be. But if I run on iPad, my HUD doesn't centre as well. It looks like my HUD still at centre of 1366 x 960.

I don't think that simulated metric's setting impacts on my HUD problem as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31949116/2924335). I am using [JGProgressHUD](https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressHUD) btw, and here is how I showed my HUD.

```
HUD = [JGProgressHUD progressHUDWithStyle:JGProgressHUDStyleDark];
HUD.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"MISC_LOADING_DATA", nil);
[HUD showInView:self.view];
```

This HUD will centre automatically at `self.view` and I think it was my .xib size that matters. My question is, how should I set .xib size that will centre my HUD on iPad and iPad Pro?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

My problem is `self.view.bounds.size` value on `viewDidLoad` is different with `self.view.bounds.size` on some method's completion handler.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // first print
    NSLog(@"Height: %f", self.view.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"Width: %f", self.view.bounds.size.width);

    [self generateData:^(BOOL result) {
        if (HUD.superview) {
            [HUD dismiss];

            // 2nd print on completion handler
            NSLog(@"Height: %f", self.view.bounds.size.height);
            NSLog(@"Width: %f", self.view.bounds.size.width);
        }
    }];
}
```

I run on iPad Pro. On first print, it gives me

```
2016-05-19 16:39:31.529 hr-akses[34013:1535416] Height: 704.000000
2016-05-19 16:39:31.529 hr-akses[34013:1535416] Width: 1024.000000
```

But on 2nd print, it gives me

```
2016-05-19 16:39:31.607 hr-akses[34013:1535416] Height: 960.000000
2016-05-19 16:39:31.607 hr-akses[34013:1535416] Width: 1366.000000
```

.
.

**SOLVED**

As [Luke Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37317921/2924335) said, autolayout is most likely not finished doing its stuff at `viewDidLoad`. I initialise my HUD on `viewWillAppear` and it solving my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This size setting you are playing with here is purely for the size of the editing screen in Interface Builder.  Your problem here is not with this setting, but with your autolayout rules, which you have not mentioned.

Try these rules for example : to fix it 4 pixels from the top, and give it a fixed width, and height, you need this :

[image: Fix 4 px from top, and fix width and height]

Then to fix it so that it is always centred horizontally, you need this :

[image: Centre item horizontally in container]

(Note carefully the ticks in the boxes, and the red marks on the position constraints - those are the ones being created there)

Now with those 4 rules in place, your item is always centred horizontally, 4 from the top, and a set width and height, on absolutely any device, from the watch to the iPad Pro.

If you now change the setting for Size in Simulated Metrics, yes the IB screen might give some errors, but the same rules will still be in place, and will still work at runtime.  The errors are simply with the layout shown in Interface Builder - ie, the rules say the item should be dead centre, but right now it isnt.

What you can do if the IB screen still shows errors, is to select the screen item that has the positioning errors, and do one of two things : [image: Update frames / contraints]

Updating frames : if you select this, it takes the rules, and applies them as if the app was running.  So if the rules say that it should be centred, and it is not currently centred in Interface Builder, then selecting this will do that centring.

Updating constraints : If you select this, IB assumes that the position of the item is actual right (if it isnt centred for eg) and rather than changing the position of the item, instead the rules themselves are changed to suit the position the item is currently in.

Have a play with those so that it sinks in - this stuff is really handy and used all the time.

Comment: All of my object displayed as well. And I did it as your suggestion, thank you. But my problem is my `self.view.bounds.size` value is based on simulated metric setting. And I still don't know why.

Comment: Your value for self.view.bounds.size are definitely dependent on device, and the view size at runtime.  I am 100% certain of that.  :)

Comment: After deciding to have a look deeper based on your suggestion, I found a strange case. See my update, please. But first, thank you so much @Luke Smith.

Comment: autolayout is most likely not finished doing its stuff at viewDidLoad.  Try calling those things on viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear - you will see them remain constant.

Comment: ps - no worries, its a pleasure.

Comment: Nah! It works! Thank you so much, @Luke Smith. I created HUD in viewWillAppear and it works great.

Comment: One thing to watch there.  viewDidLoad is only called once, obviously on first load.  viewWillAppear is called obviously when the view actually appears, but that also includes things like - say you push a view controller on top, then pop it.  So it can be called several times on the same object.  Beware then that you dont make this object several times over.  Make it an instance property, and check if it exists first before you make it, eg `if (self.hudObject == nil) { make object ..`