# Black Translucent Navigation Bar Opaque Until First Drag

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have an odd situation where I cannot for the life of me get an app to start with the `UINavigationBar` set to transparent black. The app consists of a `UINavigationController` with a `UIPageViewController` as root. These are loaded from a storyboard when the app launches.

The app runs and the UINavigationBar shows up as opaque. As soon as I start dragging the `UIPageViewController` it triggers some sort of redraw and the `UINavigationBar` becomes transparent as desired.

I tried a few different ways of setting the `UINavigationBar` to transparent black, and none of them produced behavior any different than described:

1. I set these keys in `Info.plist`:

```xml
<key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
<dict>
     <key>UINavigationBar</key>
     <dict>
         <key>Style</key>
         <string>UIBarStyleBlack</string>
         <key>Translucent</key>
         <true/>
     </dict>
</dict>
```

2. I set the `UINavigationBar` appearance in the AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

   ```
   UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
   UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
   ```
3. I subclassed `UINavigationController` and set NavigationBar properties in `viewDidLoad()`:

   ```
   navigationBar.barStyle = .black
   navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
   navigationBar.setNeedsDisplay()
   ```
4. I set the NavigationBar properties in `viewDidLoad()` of the `UIPageViewController` (the navigation controller's root view controller):

   ```
   navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
   navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
   navigationController!.navigationBar.setNeedsDisplay()
   ```

I also tried toggling the navigation bar on / off to trigger a refresh

```
    navigationController!.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    navigationController!.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

5. For the sake of completion, I set the navigation bar properties in `viewDidLoad()` of the child view controller of the `UIPageViewController`.

In every single case I get the same behavior: opaque bar until I touch the screen and start a drag, at which point it switches to transparent.

What's odd is that setting other attributes of the navigation bar, such as `titleTextAttributes`, `leftButtonItem`, and `rightButtonItem` works just fine and the changes are reflected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement  with **`Swift3`** an achieved it in this way:

1. In your view controller which contains `PageViewController` add the following code in `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
   func makeNavigationTranslucent() -> Void {
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
     self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.9)
   }
   ```

   **Note** : Change `navigationBar.backgroundColor` to the one which you want.
2. In your `storyboard` select your controller and under attribute inspector with simulated metrics heading set top bar to Navigation Translucent Bar. Refer below  image :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Note that setting Simulated Metrics in Interface Builder doesn't affect the app, it's for preview only, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31949116/1161906.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hacky solution, but I managed to get it working by hiding the default navigation bar and adding a new one over it. In the page view controller `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
navigationController!.isNavigationBarHidden = true

let newNavBar = UINavigationBar()
newNavBar.barStyle = .black
newNavBar.isTranslucent = true

newNavBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.mainFontThin(24),
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
// etc...

navigationController!.view.addSubview(newNavBar)

newNavBar.frame = CGRect(
    x:0, y:0,
    width:navigationController!.view.bounds.width,
    height:navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
)

newNavBar.pushItem(navigationItem, animated: false)
```

This shows the translucent navigation bar like we want, but there's still a small problem where the app status bar is black under the translucent nav bar. As before, once you drag a finger the status bar updates to transparent. I'm not sure how to fix this, adding a call to `setNeedsStatusBarUpdate()` didn't help. So this is a partial fix.